# Returning max version number per interval period timestamp

Tags: entity-framework, group-by

I have a dataset with the following fields:

```
IntervalPeriodTimestamp
RegisterTypeCode
ReadingReplacementVersion
IntervalValue
```

I receive readings every 30 minutes but sometimes these readings are replaced and the readingreplacementversionumber is incremented.

Using LINQ how can I return only a list of the largest reading replacementversion for each half hourly period?

I have tried:

```
db.IntervalInformations
  .Where(ii => ii.ChannelInformation.RegisterTypeCode == "62")
  .OrderBy(ii => ii.IntervalPeriodTimestamp)
  .ThenBy(ii => ii.ChannelInformation.Meter.messageType342.ReadingReplacementVersionNumber)
  .ToList();
```

This returns a list sorted by Interval Period Timestamp and then by Replacement Version but I only want to return the list of interval informations with the MAX one. I have been able to achieve this in SQL using code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  select SerialNumber, RegisterTypeCode, IntervalStatusCode, UOM_Code,
      IntervalPeriodTimestamp, ReadingReplacementVersionNumber, IntervalValue,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY IntervalPeriodTimestamp 
          ORDER BY ReadingReplacementVersionNumber desc) 
  from MarketMessage as a
  inner join messageType342 as b on a.MarketMessageID = b.MarketMessageID
  inner join Meter as c on b.messageType342ID = c.MessageType342ID
  inner join ChannelInformation as d on c.MeterID = d.MeterID
  inner join IntervalInformation as e on d.ChannelInformationID = e.ChannelInformationID 
  where MPRN = 101010101010
  and CAST(IntervalPeriodTimestamp as date) between '1 feb 2018' and '28 feb 2018'
  and RegisterTypeCode = 62
)
select * from CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Not sure how I can convert this to LINQ statement

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: group your items into the different groups from which you want only one record, order the records by `ReadingReplacementVersionNumber` in descendent order, and get the first record in each group. Easier to understand with some code:

```
db.IntervalInformations
    .Where(ii => ii.ChannelInformation.RegisterTypeCode == "62")        
    .OrderByDescending(ii => ii.ReadingReplacementVersionNumber )
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.SerialNumber, x.RegisterTypeCode, x.IntervalStatusCode })
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

The list of properties in `GroupBy` in your real query may be different. You have to define correctly the criteria for composing the groups. Include in the `GroupBy` list the combination of properties that will have the same value in each one of your groups, and different values in other groups.